# "Calling this from your main thread can lead to deadlock and/or ANRs while getting accesToken" from GoogleAuthUtil(Google Plus integration in Android)

Tags: android, google-plus, deadlock, access-token

In my android application, I am trying to get AccessToken from GoogleAuthUtil as below :

> accessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(this, mPlusClient.getAccountName(), "oauth2:" + SCOPES);

But At this line I am gettting error as below :

> > E/GoogleAuthUtil(4696): Calling this from your main thread can lead to deadlock and/or ANRs
> >     E/GoogleAuthUtil(4696): java.lang.IllegalStateException: calling this from your main thread can lead to deadlock
> >     E/GoogleAuthUtil(4696):     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.b(Unknown Source)
> >     E/GoogleAuthUtil(4696):     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
> >     E/GoogleAuthUtil(4696):     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)

Any solution of this problem? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hey @Ponting, this used to work for me, but only a few days ago it stopped working and now it throws this error com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown. Any idea why? Is there something wrong with my scopes? https://gist.github.com/lawloretienne/7351151

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try it with an AsyncTask like this:

```
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String token = null;

                try {
                    token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(
                            MainActivity.this,
                            mGoogleApiClient.getAccountName(),
                            "oauth2:" + SCOPES);
                } catch (IOException transientEx) {
                    // Network or server error, try later
                    Log.e(TAG, transientEx.toString());
                } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                    // Recover (with e.getIntent())
                    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                    Intent recover = e.getIntent();
                    startActivityForResult(recover, REQUEST_CODE_TOKEN_AUTH);
                } catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {
                    // The call is not ever expected to succeed
                    // assuming you have already verified that 
                    // Google Play services is installed.
                    Log.e(TAG, authEx.toString());
                }

                return token;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String token) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Access token retrieved:" + token);
            }

        };
        task.execute();
```

`SCOPES` is a space separated list of OAuth 2.0 scope strings.  For example `SCOPES` could be defined as:

```
public static final String SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login "
    + "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file";
```

These represent the permissions that your app is requesting from the user.  The scopes requested in this example are documented here:

- https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth
- https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files

Comment: what is the SCOPES here?

Comment: Edited my answer to explain SCOPES.

Comment: if you dont need to access drive, you shuold remove 'https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files' from scopes

Comment: Is it also possible retrieve the access token expiration time using some Android Google API? Or only through a HTTPS request?

Comment: @Lee Do you have any Clue about fetching the refresh token?

Answer (score 4):

Use separate thread for your internet code. Error is telling that **more time consuming process is running** in the app and here that is internet. So use separate thread or Async task.

Check out this link [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

> E/GoogleAuthUtil(4696): java.lang.IllegalStateException:  calling this
>   from your main thread can lead to deadlock

Sounds like you need to do that on a separate thread, have you tried that?

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) you can find information about threads in Android.

Comment: I tried with to run above code under new thread : new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { } }.start();  ..But it gives error that GoogleAuthUtil.getToken can not run on runnable method.

Answer (score 0):

```
            Thread CrearEventoHilo = new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    //do something that retrun "Calling this from your main thread can lead to deadlock"
                }
            };
            CrearEventoHilo.start();
```

### CrearEventoHilo.interrupt();

```
public class Foo {
    MyThread mTh;
    void cantBeBothered() {
        mTh = new MyThread( /*...*/ );
        mTh.run();
        mTh.start();
    }
    void imFinishedNowWaitingForThread() {
        mTh.join();
    }
    void imOutKillingOffPendingThread()  {
        mTh.interrupt();
    }
//  .....
    private class MyThread extends Thread {
//      ...;
        MyThread( /*...*/) {
//          this... = ...;
        }
        public void run() {
            doSomething( /*this...*/ );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer will be more valuable if you add an explanation on how it works.

Comment: Why the call to interrupt() ?