# Get User Token and Secret with Google API in Android

Tags: android, google-api

first of all I'm a noob Android developer. I came from iOS background and everything I see about Android development is driving me a little crazy, so apologies if what I'm about to ask is a dumb question.

I succesfully implemented a "Sign in with Google+" login in my app and now I need some information from the logged user. Here you can see some data retrieved from him.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d(TAG, "CONNECTED TO GOOGLE");

    String accountName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

    Log.d(TAG, "USER EMAIL: " + accountName);


    if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null){
        Person user = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
        Log.d(TAG, "USER NAME: "+ user.getName().getGivenName());
        Log.d(TAG, "USER IMAGE: " + user.getImage().getUrl());
        Log.d(TAG, "USER ID: " + user.getId());
    }
}
```

But I need two more things: **User's access token and user's access secret**.

I did something similar on an iOS app but I'm really lost trying to do it with Android. Anyone can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547019/calling-this-from-your-main-thread-can-lead-to-deadlock-and-or-anrs-while-getti/17547891#17547891) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096934/get-access-token-from-google-plus-android).Here it is described how you can get the access token of a google plus signed in user using a background thread.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me to get a token. But how can I get user's secret? On the Google+ API for iOS it was called "refreshToken". The token I already retrieved it was called "idToken" on the same iOS API.