# Fetching access token and sending it to server,Google+ Android

Tags: android, google-plus, access-token, google-signin

In my **android app**, i can login via **Google+** and Get the informations. 
I am new to android though.

Now i want to fetch **access token** from Google and send it to my server.

How can i do that? Please Give some code if Possible. As i am a begginer hoping explanation in easy terms.

Answer (score 0):

There's [another answer that covers getting the access token in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547019/calling-this-from-your-main-thread-can-lead-to-deadlock-and-or-anrs-while-getti/17547891#17547891).

Of note:

1) Make sure to get the token off of the UI thread in a background task
2) Ensure you're checking the correct account