# Get Google access token expiration time in Android

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth, google-signin

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547019/calling-this-from-your-main-thread-can-lead-to-deadlock-and-or-anrs-while-getti/17547891#17547891), it is possible get the Google+ access token using the following code:

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String token = null;

            try {
                token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        mGoogleApiClient.getAccountName(),
                        "oauth2:" + SCOPES);
            } catch (IOException transientEx) {
                // Network or server error, try later
                Log.e(TAG, transientEx.toString());
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                // Recover (with e.getIntent())
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                Intent recover = e.getIntent();
                startActivityForResult(recover, REQUEST_CODE_TOKEN_AUTH);
            } catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {
                // The call is not ever expected to succeed
                // assuming you have already verified that 
                // Google Play services is installed.
                Log.e(TAG, authEx.toString());
            }

            return token;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String token) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Access token retrieved:" + token);
        }
```

Is it also possible get the access token expiration date using the [GoogleAuthUtil](https://developer.android.com/index.html#q=GoogleAuthUtil) or the [AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)? Or only solutions is invoking a HTTPS POST to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth using the previous token?